# Label format in XGBoost's ndcg objective function

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm trying to use the ranking abilities of `XGBoost`, specifically using the `rank:ndcg` objective function. I have read the [learning task documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#learning-task-parameters), and tried to Google thoroughly and couldn't figure out how to format the labels for this kind of task.

Since we are talking about ranking, the label is ordered by nature - so my questions:

1. Which format does `XGBoost` expect in ranking learning tasks? (list maybe?)
2. Could it automatically account for ordinal properties of the labels so if I supply `2` as a label it will be punished more severely if the prediction was `0` than `1`?